# Create multiple popup in a window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am still pretty new to jQuery and am trying to figure out how to create multiple popup within a window. I want it such that each text opens up a different popup, containing different content. And i want the popup to close when i click outside the popup, instead of closing only when i press Esc. Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
     <div id="main">
           <h1 class="button" id="applepie">Apple Pie</h1>
                <div class="modal-mask"></div>
                <div class="modal-popup">hello</div>

                <h3>Asian Noodles</h3>
                <div class="modal-mask"></div>
                <div class="modal-popup">hello</div>


                <h3>Avocado Roll</h3>
                <div class="modal-mask"></div>
                <div class="modal-popup">hello</div>


                <h3>Bruscetta</h3>
                <div class="modal-mask"></div>
                <div class="modal-popup">bye</div>


                <h3>Bagels</h3>
                <div class="modal-mask"></div>
                <div class="modal-popup">eat</div>


                <h3>Banana Pudding</h3>
                <div class="modal-mask"></div>
                <div class="modal-popup">hungey</div>


     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.modal-mask{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.4;
    display:none;
    }



.modal-popup{
     position:fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     width: 5%;
     height: 5%;
     z-index: 101;
     background-color:#fff; 
     display:none;
     }
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
  $(".button").on("click", function(){

    $(".modal-mask").css("display", "block");
    $(".modal-popup").css("display", "block");


  $(document).on("keydown", function(event){
   if(event.keyCode === 27){
    $(".modal-mask").css("display", "");
       $(".modal-popup").css({
           "display": "",
           "width": "",
           "height": "",
           "top": "",
           "left": ""
       });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: just a suggestion use a single popup inside it add all the contents to be displayed regarding on the selected or clicked object show the corresponding content inside the modal and hide rest of the content inside the modal

Comment: What is the problem or issue you are having?

Comment: @user3127499 ok, i'll try that. but currently, even when i only have one popup modal, it does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: @cale_b issue is: currently my popup is not working. Also, I want each   popup for each text to contain different information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your Code with escape detection and modal popup for corresponding Header Clicked](http://jsfiddle.net/4NzFb/6/)

### Solved

- First change to your code wrapped each header and 2 modal divs in content wrapper div
- Upon On click of header the parent object is detected and 2nd and 3 element `display:block` is set and vice versa

### HTML

```
<div id="main">
     <h1 class="button" id="applepie">Apple Pie</h1>

     <div id="Container1">
    <div class="modal-mask"></div>
    <div class="modal-popup">hello</div>
    </div>  
    <div id="Container2">
     <h3>Asian Noodles</h3>
    <div class="modal-mask"></div>
    <div class="modal-popup">hello</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Container3">
     <h3>Avocado Roll</h3>

    <div class="modal-mask"></div>
    <div class="modal-popup">hello</div>
    </div>
    <div id="Container4">
     <h3>Bruscetta</h3>

    <div class="modal-mask"></div>
    <div class="modal-popup">bye</div>
    </div>
 <div id="Container5">
        <h3>Bagels</h3>

    <div class="modal-mask"></div>
    <div class="modal-popup">eat</div>
  
    </div>
    <div id="Container6">
     <h3>Banana Pudding</h3>

    <div class="modal-mask"></div>
    <div class="modal-popup">hungey</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

### JQUERY

```
$("h3").on("click", function () {

 //   $(".modal-mask").css("display", "block");
//    $(".modal-popup").css("display", "block");
 $(".modal-mask").css("display", "none");
  $(".modal-popup").css("display", "none");
$($(this).parents().children()[1]).toggle();       
$($(this).parents().children()[2]).toggle();
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {

  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
   $(".modal-mask").css("display", "none");
  $(".modal-popup").css("display", "none");
  }   // esc
});
  
});

//Click out-side pop-up that ie on the mask close
$(".modal-mask").on("click", function(){

      $(".modal-mask").css("display", "none");
  $(".modal-popup").css("display", "none");
});
```

### CSS

```
.modal-mask {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-color:#000;
    opacity:0.4;
    display:none;
}
.modal-popup {
    position:fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 15%;
    height: 15%;
    z-index: 101;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:none;
}

h3{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red , blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right, red , blue); /* Standard syntax */
    
}
h3:hover{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, blue , red); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(right, blue,red ); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(right,blue ,red ); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  blue,red ); /* Standard syntax */
    
}
```

### Output

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: Cool. I think that works. I've another qn though: any idea to have it such that i can close the popup by clicking outside the modal (on the mask area), instead of pressing the esc key?

Answer (score 1):

Catch all click events by listening on the document, but 
using event delegate notation so we can figure out the 
lowest-level element where the  click originated. Like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(){
    //alternatively, you can use the 'keydown' event, as you have.

    //if the click did *not* bubble up through the modal, 
    //then the click was outside it, on something else:
    if(!$(this).parents().hasClass('modal-popup'){
        //do what you need to do when user clicks outside the modal
        //i.e. close the modal
    }
})
```